# Lighttpd: Let sub-path point to different document root

Tags: lighttpd, subdirectory, document-root

I have a lighttpd-Setup pointing to the document-root `/var/www`. However, I want the URL `other/` to point to `/some/other/dir`. This I'm doing with the following config:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/other($|/)" {
  server.document-root = "/some/other/dir"
}
```

However, if I access 'http://myhost/other', lighttpd tries to access `/some/other/dir/other` instead of just `/some/other/dir`. Is it possible to somehow strip the `/other` but keep any further URL segments? So for instance, `http://myhost/other/sub/foo.txt` should point to `/some/other/dir/sub/foo.txt`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of trying to set `server.document-root`, you can use `mod_alias` to achieve this:

```
server.modules = ( ..., "mod_alias" )

...

alias.url = ( "/other/" => "/some/other/dir/" )
```

This will create an alias such that all requests to `/other/` and resources inside that folder will be redirected to `/some/other/dir/` on the file system, with a request directly to `/other/` being pointed directly to the root of `/some/other/dir/`, just like you want.

Comment: I can confirm that the above works in 2021 still. I had to alias a directory with autogenerated images just now (I abandoned apache's httpd in favour of lighttpd years ago because apache became more and more complex; also the config format change annoyed me). After using the alias.url= specification I could simply map it onto "/images/" and that works; all images are displayed fine, including the display from a .cgi file (I still use them in 2021!). Don't forget the trailing / there as that one seems important.